# How do I set allowInvalidContainer in SigmaJS?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

First things first, I am absolutely inexperienced so apologies if this is a simple solution, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere else after repeated Googling error messages. I'm working on a project that has to be done by tomorrow that in this final step requires me to use SigmaJS, even though I admittedly don't understand JS all that well.

So I launch a clean template code sandbox from SigmaJS's website (https://www.sigmajs.org/), using this link (https://githubbox.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/main/examples/custom-rendering). I open it up, everything works fine. Then, as a simple test, I added a new node, "Joe", using the exact same node declaration.

After that I get this "container has no width" error (screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QvwM.png)). I just have to demonstrate proof of concept for a presentation so it doesn't have to work on a webpage or anything, it just needs to run for five minutes in the sandbox, so I just want to clean up that error short term. allowInvalidContainer looks like what I need, but how do I use it? `allowInvalidContainer = true;` has not worked.

Again, apologies, I'm sure to experienced programmers this is simple. I just really need to get my nodes and edges added and keep it running without crashing for five minutes or so, and I think I'm stuck on that front, so anything helps. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Resolved: for anyone who finds this thread googling the error message you have to declare allowInvalidContainer inside const renderer at the end, see screenshot below

[image: 1]

Comment: for those you can't see the image, this should be your solution this.renderer = new Sigma(this.graph, this.container, {allowInvalidContainer: true});